# JSON date format reader

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi all i am working on jquery we are trying to read json date the format is like this 2013-12-20T02:26:23.337 we are removing time stamp and only want to show mm-dd-year format he is the code we are using we are not getting proper month one month delay we are getting output is: 11/20/2013  how to resolve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var d = "2013-12-20T02:26:23.337";
 var year = new Date(d).getFullYear();
 var month = new Date(d).getMonth();
 var date = new Date(d).getDate();
 var formatdate = month  + "/" + date + "/" + year;

   var x = document.getElementById("demo");

  x.innerHTML=formatdate;
      });
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <p id="demo"></p>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: month is `0-based`, just need to +1 for month. Also recommend that you call `new Date(d)` only once and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp:

The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.

Note: January is 0, February is 1, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`getMonth()`  returns Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December. You need to add `+1` i.e. `new Date(d).getMonth()+1;`

```
 var d = "2013-12-20T02:26:23.337";
var year = new Date(d).getFullYear();
var month = new Date(d).getMonth()+1;
var date = new Date(d).getDate();
var formatdate = month  + "/" + date + "/" + year;

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

x.innerHTML=formatdate;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/76QSZ/1/

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date